# How do I make items disappear when resizing with a responsive webdesign?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm using a facebook comment box and I can't make it shrink when the screen resolution shrinks. My span classes don't have any effect on it. I'm trying to make the comment box disappear once the screen size goes below the width of the box.

Is it possible to make it disappear once it hits its max width?

Comment: Yes, with media queries. You are in control of the elements that embed the fb comment box, so just place a media query statement on that element and tell it to hide for screens less than x width

Answer (score 4):

Yes for sure, in your css write

```
// REGULAR OL' CSS

span#yourspan { display:block }

// MEDIA QUERY

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    span#yourspan { display:none }
}
```

Some further reading on it :)

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/introducing-media-queries.html

One small question, is your facebook box in an iframe?

Comment: if you **really** want to keep it you could also think about using transforms on your iframe like: transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); but its more of a hack and may look wierd (I don't know what the facebook box looks like).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest CSS media queries (almost every time), but a straight-forward answer has already been given and I'd recommend that. However, if you're using jQuery and already have a resize event at hand, it might seem easier to simply expand on that. This will make the comment box come back if the screen should enlarge again.

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    windowWidth = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (windowWidth < YOUR_FACEBOOK_WIDTH) {

        $("#YOUR_COMMENT_BOX").hide();

    } else if (windowWidth >= YOUR_FACEBOOK_WIDTH) {

        $("#YOUR_COMMENT_BOX").show();

    }

});
```

Comment: It's not the optimal solution, but since somebody already mentioned media queries, I thought to offer another suggestion.

Comment: I can see your point but media queries are universally supported and syntactically much much more concise. It is best to not even develop a habit of avoiding current standards, especially when "responsive" design is becoming so critical these days

Comment: I agree with you, but there's always that %1 of the time when this solution could be more suitable, for anybody that stumbles on this in the future. Recently I built a naturally responsive site that didn't need media queries (was using Masonry v2), so when I had something that needed to change on resize, I found it easier to insert it in the resize event that was already there for something else.

Comment: fair enough. I'll plus if you update your answer with this case situation and note the other answer about css method